# Sci-fi book about a teen boy that meets an alien boy in human form and becomes friends with him

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read this sci-fi book back in about 1987 in school, at least twice. All I can really remember is it's about a teen boy that meets an alien in human form and they become friends.

In one part, they are in an unoccupied house and I believe the alien was injured and he slowed down time so he could heal. I believe there was a bully involved in the story also.

Been about 34 years since I read it. I'm guessing it was written back in the early '80s. It's not the book *Aliens Ate My Homework*. Would really love to find it again and buy a copy.

Comment: i asked about a similar story but i have no memory of injury or bully -- i think i read only the first book of the two. do u remember anything else about the bully subplot?

Answer (score 4):

[The Space Ship Under the Apple Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Ship_Under_the_Apple_Tree). Here's a very brief synopsis of it from book 2 of the series, *The Space Ship Returns to the Apple Tree*:

> What travels faster than light, but looks like a peanut roaster? Marty's new Bamboozerlergical Metal Martinean Interspacial Superphotic Astral Rocket Disk, of course! The twelve year old from space is back for another summer of adventure with his pal Eddie. This time, the boys want to tour the United States, but there is one small problem--they only have four days to do it and Marty hasn't quite learned to fly his new ship..
>
> [image]

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you describe how this matches the details given in the question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  The Wikipedia page you've linked to has very few details about the story; can you confirm any of the plot points mentioned in the question appear in the story?  For example, the alien being injured and slowing down time.  You might want to read [answer] and take the [tour].